# How do I get the value of a select element that goes through a DataTable?

Tags: c#, html, angular

This is where I get my data from. I get all this data through a controller in C# and I save it to `locations`.

```
 locations: any=[];

 getLocations()
  {
    this.service.getRuimList().subscribe(data =>
      this.locations = data)
  }
```

So this is my `select` element, I go through the `locations`, which is of type DataTable.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Kies een locatie</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedLocation.name" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
          <option *ngFor='let location of locations' [value]='location'>{{location.Locatie}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      locatie: {{selectedLocation.name}}
```

The locations data has 3 columns: RuimteId, Locatie and Capaciteit. I want to be able to save the selected location (the name but also id and capacity) whenever the user selects a location. I tried as you can see above, in my HTML file, but I get this as result:

[image: How it looks like in the app]

I also tried mapping `locations` and save all the attributes of the selected location in variables, but that way my select element doesn't show any elements anymore.

Comment: [value]='location.locatie'..?

Comment: @MikeOne sorry, it's a mix between dutch & english... anyways, location refers to "let location of locations" where as Locatie is the column name, coming from my SQL database. So basically for every item of locations, I try to get  "Locatie" (so the name) in my select element.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you need. You are putting the entire Location object in the dropdown value now. If you want to see what the value becomes once a selection has been made, try locatie: {{selectedLocation.name | json}}.. or otherwise locatie: {{selectedLocation.name.locatie}} should work..

Comment: ... I think my first comment might still be what you need if I understand you correctly..

Comment: @MikeOne yes indeed! I reread your first comment and I tried that and it is indeed what I needed, thanks!